# Amazon SNS is crashed with SNSInvalidParameterException in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, ios8, amazon-sns

I have implemented AWS - Simple Notification Service and it was working fine, but after I upgraded my iOS 7 to iOS 8 application is crashed with :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AmazonClientException', reason: ''
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x186f3e084 0x19751c0e4 0x100270224 0x10026f95c 0x1000dd7f0 0x187e0a60c 0x197d3fe80 0x197d3fddc 0x197d3cfb0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type SNSInvalidParameterException

After execution of below code snippet its crashing,

```
endPoint.platformApplicationArn = @"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:ID:app/APNS_SANDBOX/AppName_Dev";
[amazonClient createPlatformEndpoint:endPoint];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can turn on the verbose logging by calling `[AmazonLogger verboseLogging];`. It may give you more information. Also, we released the [AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/). It contains many improvements, so you may want to consider migrating.

Comment: Yosuke thank you for your comment. Now Im getting following error like this - <Message>Invalid parameter: Token Reason: Endpoint arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:ID:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/APP_NAME/e285b5b6-d5ea-3w22-8348-08837b89a7e4 already exists with the same Token, but different attributes.</Message>?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've got an solution, this is due to not using same user data for `endPoint.customUserData`. As Yosuke commented `[AmazonLogger verboseLogging];` helped me a lot in tracking the bug.

So try to use same data (as in here @"Test") for one application.

```
endPoint.customUserData = @"Test";
```